# Initilize some test data with YAML on Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, yaml

I have creating a learning application with play framework and i want to use test data which is loaded from yaml. But my data's are just null in mysql, for example

```
@Entity
public class DiningTable extends Model{

Integer number;

public DiningTable(Integer number) {
    super();
    this.number = number;
}

}
```

This is my diningTable class and this are my test data;

```
DiningTable(tab1):
 number: 1
DiningTable(tab2):
 number: 2
DiningTable(tab3):
 number: 3
DiningTable(tab4):
 number: 4
```

I'm starting my application and it calls the bootstrap which is loads the yaml data and there will be no error but in my phpmyadmin, diningtable table it's contains this data;

```
id  number
1   NULL
2   NULL
3   NULL
4   NULL
```

What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem changing this in the model

```
 Integer number
```

to

```
 public Integer number
```

Answer (score 1):

Or:
keep the value private:

```
private Integer number;
```

And add Getter/Setters.

```
public Integer getNumber(){ return number;}
public void setNumber(Integer num){this.number = num;}
```

The bootstrap loader finds the values through Reflections... so either make the values public or use getter/setters.